# Establish SSH connection when two servers all behind firewalls both don't accept incoming connections

Tags: ssh, linux-networking

Here is ths network diagram

```
|--local network A--|                                                   |--local network B--| 
|      Server A     | firewall A |-- ipv6 only internet -- | firewall B |      Server B     |
|-------------------|                                                   |-------------------|
```

Both Firewall A and B are only allow outcoming connections and don't accept incoming connections. Both server runs Ubuntu 18.

Is that possible to Establish a SSH connection from A to B or B to A? I want the two server clould talk to each other directly.

If not, I have a server C on Internet could accept incoming connections from both server A and B, but server C have limited bandwith, is there a way to let server C help A and B establish a SSH connection without relaying by C?

I've Goolged about VPN. As far as I know it also requires at least one server could accept incoming connections, or relay by a Server C. I hope they can communicate directly.

Comment: is using ngrok an option? https://ngrok.com

Comment: Just read the introduction about ngrok. It might not an option. I think it will transmit all traffic through a public server? I need transport a lot of data (hundreads GB) as fast as posibble. @BANJOSA

Comment: I understand, and at the end of the day this also poses a security risk, since you are sending your data through an "unknown" server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get A or B to see each other's LANs, opening the firewall to allowed traffic is the easy way. If your organization has a use case for connecting these networks, the firewall policy should be changed.

Could be implemented in several ways: a VPN (IPSec, OpenVPN, WireGuard), some SD-WAN controller that manages VPN links for you, or perhaps direct from the Internet to the applications if they are encrypted and hardened (https web apps).

Both connecting to C grants them access to C's network. Think connecting to a cloud. However, you requested direct from A to B. Also, infrastructure hosts in using C as a hub node.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transfer a lot of data, i would suggest using [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/).

By default it will use public relays if no direct connectivity between hosts. Protocol and transfer are encrypted, but if you're still worried, you could run your own [relay](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/strelaysrv.html) on C, and [setting it](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/relaying.html) on A and B.